# mysql - node - Row inserted and queryable via server connection lost on DB restart

Tags: mysql, node.js

I ran into an issue testing today that occurred during or after an insert via a connection on my node server.  The code where the insert is performed looks something like this:

```
// ...
username = esc(username);
firstname = esc(firstname);
lastname = esc(lastname);
var values = [username, firstname, lastname].join(',');
var statement = 'INSERT INTO User(Username,FirstName,LastName) VALUES({0});\n'+
    'SELECT FirstName, LastName, Username, Id, IsActive FROM User WHERE Username={1};'
statement = merge( statement, [ values, username ] );
conn.query(statement, function(e, rows, fields){
    e ? function() {
        res.status(400);
        var err = new Error;
        err.name = 'Bad request';
        err.message = 'A problem occurred during sign-up.';
        err.details = e;
        res.json(err);
    }() : function(){
        res.json( rows[1] );
    }();
}
```

*A quick note on `esc()` and `merge()`, these are simply util functions that help prepare the database statement.*

The above code completed successfully, ie. the response was a 200 with the newly inserted user row in the body. The row inserted was queryable via the same connection throughout the day.  I only noticed this afternoon when running the following generic query as root via shell, the row was missing.

`SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM User;`

So at that point I restarted the database and the node server.  Unfortunately.  Now it would appear the row is gone entirely, as well as any reliable path to troubleshoot.

Here are some details of interest to my server setup.  As of yet, no idea how (if at all) any of these could be suspect.

1. Uses only single connection as opposed to conn pool (for now)
2. `multipleStatements=true` in the connection config (obviously above snippet makes use of this)
3. `SET autocommit = 0;` `START TRANSACTION;` `COMMIT;` used elsewhere in the codebase to control rollback
4. Using poor man's keep-alive every 30 seconds to avoid connection timing out: `SELECT 1;`

I've been reading up all evening and am running out of ideas.  Any suggestions?  Is this likely an issue of uncommitted data?  If so, is there a reliable way to debug this?  Better yet, is there any way to prevent it?  What could be the cause?  And finally, if in debugging my server I find data in this state, is there a way to force commit at least so that I don't lose my changes?

Comment: I would suspect the autocommit with the single connection. If the session never dies because you are keeping the connecteion open, and you have set autocommit off, then I would suspect that your item didn't get committed. Not positive, but it seems suspect.

Comment: It does stand out.  According to the mysql guide: 'With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state.'  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

In case of an error, does ROLLBACK need to be invoked explicitly?

Comment: Not positive, been a while since I have used it. We're mostly a NoSQL shop now. You could explicitly set it on before your transaction starts.